# Where am I going wrong with calculating the divergence of a vector function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

$x' = y + x (\alpha - x^2 - y^2)$

$y' = -x + y (1 - x^2 - y^2)$

I believe that I have figured out its polar coordinate form.

$r' = r \left[ (\alpha - 1) \cos^2 \theta + 1 - r^2 \right]$

$\theta' = -1 - (\alpha - 1) \sin \theta \cos \theta$

I am trying to calculate the divergence.

$F_r = r' = r \left[ (\alpha - 1) \cos^2 \theta + 1 - r^2 \right]$

$F_\theta = \theta' = -1 - (\alpha - 1) \sin \theta \cos \theta$

$F_z = 0$

I should be using the cylindrical version of the divergence method, no?

$ \text{div} F = \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r F_r \right) + \frac{1}{r} \frac{d F_\theta}{d \theta} + \frac{d F_z}{dz}$

When I substitute everything in and work out the algebra, I get

$ r F_r = (\alpha - 1) r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 - r^4$

$\frac{d}{dr}(r F_r) = 2 (\alpha - 1) r \cos^2 \theta + 2r - 4r^3$

$\frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}(r F_r) = 2 (\alpha - 1) \cos^2 \theta + 2 - 4r^2$

and

$F_\theta = -1 - (\alpha - 1) \sin \theta \cos \theta$

$\frac{d F_\theta}{d \theta} = -(\alpha - 1) \left( \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta \right)$

$\frac{1}{r} \frac{d F_\theta}{d \theta} = -\frac{\alpha - 1}{r} \left( \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta \right)$

so

$ \text{div} F = 2 (\alpha - 1) \cos^2 \theta + 2 - 4 r^2 - \frac{\alpha - 1}{r} \left( \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta \right)$

But I was checking the book and it seems that I should be getting

$\text{div} F = \alpha + 1 - 4 r^2$

I checked and tried many times but it doesn't seem to work out. Where did I go wrong? Maybe it is my derivation?

[[image: My Calculation of <span class=]$\text{div} F$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnSLj.jpg)
[[image: My Derivation of <span class=]$\theta'$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa2nz.jpg)

[[image: My Derivation of <span class=]$r'$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiR9F.png)

Comment: You didn't introduce $F$?

Comment: $F_r$, $F_\theta$ and $F_z$ are my $F$ components.

Comment: For $\alpha=1$, $r'^2=x'^2+y'^2=(x^2+y^2)(1+(1-x^2+y^2)^2)=r^2(1+(1-r^2)^2)$. That doesn't seem to match what you have for $r'$ for $\alpha=1$?

Comment: I got the same derivation as in the book. I also used the method of elimination to solve for $r'$ and $\theta'$.

Comment: Is that an [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority)? :-) Perhaps you could point out where my argument is wrong, or show your own derivation? (Or the one from the book, if you prefer.)

Comment: Lol, I hope I didn't sound like I want to argue. I will show my derivations.